# My controller always shoots wide compared to keyboard in FIFA '15?

Tags: pc, fifa-15

In FIFA 15 I'm using *Assist* for the shot assistance, but the shot is not accurate at all. The ball directly goes to the direction that I press from the stick like in *manual* shot assistance. Is that normal?

I can't figure out how to avoid going wide of the goal every time. Always this happens to me even inside the box. I don't have this problem when I play using keyboard and always happens when I play using my controller and I didn't have this problem in FIFA 14.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Are you sure that the controller assist settings are the same as the keyboard settings? The controller may be set to manual while the keyboard is assisted.

Comment: Yes. Both are set to Assist. I've seen that this problem is common for the most of the people in other forums too